# Wordpress adding uploaded media directly to post

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to achieve is to add file uploaded from the media library directly to a post. 
Is it possible to give the user choice in wp-admin, to which post he would like to add the uploaded media ? (i am talking about adding media from the media library)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can easily add media from Media Library to your post without visiting Post page..
Follow this tutorial:

Step #1: Go to your WordPress Media Library.

Step #2: In Media Library you will find many images, Media Library show you 4 different columns which is "File, author, upload-to and date" in upload to column you will see an attach link click on that link

Step #3: Select the post where you want to attach that image..

repeat these steps to attach every new image with every other post

From these steps you can send media from media library.

Comment: That works for media already uploaded. I am looking for solution to attach media in the upload view